# How to assign a key on a laptop to right click?

Tags: windows-8, mouse

I recently bought a brand new Toshiba laptop. i5, 8GB, 1TB and everything. One problem I've been having with it, though, is that the mouse buttons are really tough to push down. Both left and right buttons. I can get by with the left mouse button by tapping the touch pad, but now the right button... How would I setup the, let's say...right ALT button to emulate pressing the right mouse button?

I could get an external mouse, but I don't want to carry a desk and mouse pad around with me, or just click the dang mouse button, but after a while my finger get's sore.

Comment: check [this](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.autohotkey.com%2F&ei=u8yMVcjbIIK2mQXNkKeQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFPilXcl_JZc0P02lpflIlG3G-Q-w&sig2=ChXoS7AdIHbobcIgpkHxlQ) out, but there will be some problem with Alt combination like Alt + F4 will fail

Comment: Do you have this [key](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=toshiba+right+click+key+%2B+keyboard&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=709&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PNSMVbuhL5CLuATvkaDgCQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=sABxjUzYGD-UaM%253A%3Bd7ygIZ6PEN1YzM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog.laptopmag.com%252Fwpress%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2012%252F07%252FThinkPad-Keyboard-Face-Off_g4-T420.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fblog.laptopmag.com%252Fthinkpad-type-off-is-lenovos-new-island-style-keyboard-better-or-worse%3B675%3B400) on your keyboard. What's your model?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath Yes I have a key very similar to that, upon pressing, nothing happens. My model is Satellite C55-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out how to do this in AutoHotKey, thanks to Bilo letting me know about it.

Here's the script if anyone's curious:

```
RAlt::RButton
```